# How to send a request using ngForward when upgrading from angularjs to angular?

Tags: angular

Sending a request using ES5 standard(javascript) and the right way to inject the http dependency in a service and NOT component

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to inject an http object in a service. It should work in the same way in a component:-

In the constructor of a service, add the following code.

```
constructor (http: Http)
```

This would work well after you import the Http into your typescript using the following code:-

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

And add HttpModule to your project's NgModule's imports

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is in typescript and the ES 6 standard, I want it in ES5 javascript